# App Xamarin Forms se cierra cuando la empiezo a depurar

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

estoy haciendo una app en xamarin forms con visual studio 2019. Cuando depuro la aplicación en el emulador de android no tengo ningun problema pero cuando la intento depurar en un emulador iphone entonces la aplicación hace como que abre pero se cierra de inmediato y no muestra ningun error en ningún lado lo cual no me permite debuggear.Lo raro es que cuando la abro desde el emulador la app si abre y funciona pero en modo debug no me deja depurarla con visual studio. Alguna idea?.

Comment: Deba haber un problema con tu archivo Info.plist, pon el log de salida en verbose, para que te diga exactamente que es, a mi me pasó exactamente lo mismo alguna ocasión.

Answer (score 0):

Hola fíjate la consola de salida de visual studio, debe estar en el mensaje ahí de porque no funciona correctamente, copia y pega aquí así lo miramos.